# Class attribute docstring inside class docstring block

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring

I'm documenting my Python project with Sphinx, and want to document class attributes inside the class docstring block. Attribute inline docstrings are ugly.

I did try adding attribute docstring to class docstring block but when Sphinx makes html, it does not show properly.

```
class MyClass():
    """
        MyClass docstring block.

        Attributes:
            name - A single attribute.
            :attr name - A single attribute.
    """

    name = "ABC"
```

The generated html displays a simple line. Instead with attribute inline docstring display a nice style.

[Attribute inline docstring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt7kI.png)

[Attribute docstring in class block docstring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHfZL.png)

Comment: Do not post images of code. Post your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

You should put a colon *after* the attribute name:

```
class MyClass():
    """MyClass docstring block.

        Attributes:
            name: A single attribute.
            name: A single attribute.
    """

    name = "ABC"
```

Comment: Thank you @Serge Ballesta I tried that. No results.